# Avoid session time out in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, session

I pass all the necessary data using session variable and when session expires all the data will be lost. I want it not to expire on a particular jsp but when in other jsps session it can expire.

I propose sending a request to the server continuously according to the timer to avoid the session expiry in particular jsp.

I use spring mvc. How can I do this on particular jsp?

I tried below code but I need to do is send a request to the server without using image:

```
function keepMeAlive(imgName) {
   myImg = document.getElementById(imgName);
   if (myImg) myImg.src = myImg.src.replace(/?.*$/, '?' + Math.random());
}
window.setInterval("keepMeAlive('keepAliveIMG')", 100000);

<img id="keepAliveIMG" width="1" height="1" src="http://www.some.url/someimg.gif?" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function f(){
              var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var sURL = "http://"
         + "localhost:8080/sessionAlivecheck/"
         + "/example/newjsp.jsp";

oRequest.open("GET",sURL,false);
oRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent",navigator.userAgent);
oRequest.send(null);
//alert("hhh");
          }

          $(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(f, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax calls:

```js
function keepAlive(){
    $.get( window.location.pathname, function( data ) {console.log(data)} );
}

window.setInterval(keepAlive, 100000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```